# Trying to get a new user up on pfSense IPSec VPN; Config file import failed, now getting gateway errors

Tags: vpn, configuration, ipsec, pfsense

Caveat: I am not a sysadmin, so please forgive the n00bness of the query. We have a new user and I'm trying to get them up on VPN. We use pfsense as an IPSEC endpoint. This person is using Shrewsoft for the client. I had created an entry in pfsense for them and then edited a previous user's config file.

Shrewsoft didn't import the config file very well and I had to hand edit the information. Now we are getting gateway errors. One thing I've noticed is that there is a different between the values of the preshared key stored on the firewall and the psk stored in the config file.

I assume it has something to do with a hash, but I've no idea if that's the case and whether that might be what's causing the problem. Any suggestions greatly appreciated! Tangentially, is there some software used to generate these config files?

Comment: +1 for using the word "Tangentially". Oh, and I made your title more descriptive to get more eyes on the thread. =)